# ConstraintSet doesn't work with nested ConstraintLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I have two activities, `activity_main.xml` and `activity_main_details.xml` and I want the elements from the first activity to transition to the second one.

First activity:

[image]

This activity is made up of two separate constraint layouts which are included in another layout. Code below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:transitionName="firstHalf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:transitionName="photo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/add_log_here"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:transitionName="title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photo" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:transitionName="secondHalf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline">

     <-- more code here -->>
```

Second activity is:

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    tools:context=".authenthicaton.joinUs.add_company_logo_animation">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:transitionName="firstHalf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:transitionName="photo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/add_log_here"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:transitionName="title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.08" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:transitionName="secondHalf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline">
     <-- more code here -->
```

The issue is that there should be a transition for the elements:

- > photo `@+id/photo`
- > textView `@+id/textView4`

They should change the position from the first activity to the second one. In other words the second activity should be the result after the animation.

Here is the actual kotlin code:

```
        val root = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)
        var set = false
        val constraint1 = ConstraintSet()
        constraint1.clone(root)
        val constraint2 = ConstraintSet()
        constraint2.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_details)
        val floatingActionButton = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floatingActionButton)

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                val transition = ChangeBounds()
                transition.duration = 300
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root, transition)
                val constraint = if(set) constraint1 else constraint2
                constraint.applyTo(root)
                set = !set
            }
        }
```

My result (after the animation) :

[image]

As you can see the photo and the textview haven't changed their first position. This being the reason to why they are not there.
I have also tried to use `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` but this complicated my code a lot because of the focus(related to edittext boxes) issues I had.

Does anyone know why the photo and the textview havent changed like they should've done? Is constrainSet having issues with nested Constrained layouts?

Comment: Working as intended, `constraintSet` was never intended to recursively clone child layouts. You might want to manually clone each `constraintLayout` child or write your own utility function to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been successful with `ConstrainSet` so I ended up using `scene` which really worked in my case.

Due to the fact that I have multiple nested `ConstrainedLayouts` , `ConstrainedSet` is not going to work as @Pawel pointed out. Declaring `ConstrainedSet` for each of the subchildren didn't worked either.

Anyway, this is my solution using `scene`.

```
val transition = ChangeBounds()

transition.duration = 800

val scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root),
                                         R.layout.activity_main_details,
                                         this)
findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floatingActionButton).setOnClickListener {
            TransitionManager.go(scene, transition)
// more code here
}
```